# Java Получение продолжительности видеофайла на ПК

Tags: java, файлы, kotlin

Есть видео файл на ПК. Каким образом я могу получить продолжительность этого видео в Java/Kotlin?

Пытался получить через nio, но там, либо нету возможности получить этот атрибут, либо я что-то неправильно делаю.

**Update**: Решил данную проблему через подключение xuggle. Написал следующую функцию, чтобы получать длительность в миллисекундах:

```
fun getFileDuration(path: String): Long {
    val container = IContainer.make()
    container.open(path, IContainer.Type.READ, null)
    var duration =  container.duration / 1000
    container.close()
    return duration
}
```

Это работает, но занимает слишком много времени. 200+ файлов обрабатываются очень долго, а предусматривается обработка еще большего количества. Можно ли как-то оптимизировать скорость работы данного кода? Если нет, то что можно использовать как более быструю альтернативу? Есть ли такая возможность в JavaFX или каких-либо других библиотеках?

Comment: А если через ffmpeg как-то получить?

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой класс `MediaMetaDataRetriever`:

```
 MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
 retriever.setDataSource(context, videoUri);
 String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
 int duration = Integer.parseInt(time);
 retriever.release();
```

Если в видео нет метаданных (редко но такое бывает), то не сработает.

Также с помощью этого класса удобно получать thumbnail'ы видео, стоп кадры и проч. полезности.

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever)

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то данный класс принадлежит к библиотекам для android, а мне же нужно реализовать это для ПК. Могу я как-то использовать данный класс в моем случае?

Comment: Упс, не обратил внимания на теги... `MediaMetaDataRetriever` работает только для Android, для desktop Java надо смотреть на другие либы